# Caching OG data in the debugger, forcing og:type website, and authorization popup for "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" woes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

Having issues getting Timeline to work. It is a two part problem.

First, there is an issue of caching parts of the OG metatags. When the debugger goes to my URL, I know it is hitting it correctly because the og:url it spits back is correct which means it has been processed on my end (ex: I send it to og.php?og=read&chapter=799, and it will spit back the right book_id for the og:url, meaning my script processed it). But all the other information seems to be cached. I originally and erroneously had an fb:app_id and og:site_url for an object, so I removed those. The output still shows those as having an existing site_url which is throwing an error. Having a fb:app_id forces the og:type of 'website', which I have set (correctly) to my namespace and object. When I try to POST the action, I get an oAuthException error back, that an og:type of 'website' isn't valid for an object. Once again, that should be fixed, but it keeps caching the old OG data. I have tried adding ?fbrefresh=1, but that did nothing.

Another issue, possibly related...even though I know it got there, and my script processed the request, Facebook doesn't report that. When I click on "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" it shows the authentication URL (see below)! As though, it never got there and the popup was initiated, which isn't even how the code for og.php works!! My guess is they got that from the base domain name itself (exmaple.com) before trying the full request with example.com/og.php.

window.parent.location='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=164431733642252&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fexample%2F%3Fpage%3D&state=064bd26ff582a9ec7c96729e6b69bbd2&canvas=1&fbconnect=0&scope=email%2Cpublish_stream%2Cpublish_actions%2C';

Comment: Please care to format your question properly. Make use of paragraphs with proper formatting. Your question itself looks somewhat horrible and may give someone a headache.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I thought the og:url was the URL you wanted people to use to get to the correct page in your app, like an action link. It is, but it isn't. I now have it match the OBJECT_URL you send to timeline.

I had a different URL (an action link to the app), which when redirected, can't be reached by the crawler because it is inside the applications authorized wall. This caused the og:type of website, and data to appear cached.

To fix it, the object_url I post to timeline, and the og:url in the metatag is the same. But you can figure out if it is the crawler or the action link by looking for the query string: ?fb_action_ids=SOME_ID which is sent from link on the timeline. If it contains that, then I forward it to the application page needed from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems to you. It kept complaining about og:site_url being set, even though I never set those. It appears that the error messages it sends are actually inaccurate, and the problem is not that og:site_url is being set, but that the og:url is different from the object url. Sometimes a wrong error message is worse than no error message!

A further question is why an object url has to correspond to a live page that a user will see. An object is a logical unit, but it doesn't necessarily correspond to a single user-visible page. Your redirection trick might work, but it is not the proper way to do something. When I post an action related to an obect, the object url should be used to draw the information of the object, but I should be able to send the user somewhere else. If this was an intended design I think it is a mistake.

Comment: Exactly. It's not perfect, but with a lot of things Facebook, my code contains hacks and workarounds. The main annoyance is occasionally, FB will fix the problem, and add working code, which then, breaks my hack. Maybe there is a better way to do it, but for now it works like a charm.